# How to get position() of particular container type in xsl

Tags: xslt, position, containers, xslt-2.0

As position function returns the position() of current node without considering the type of node. how to get postion of current particulat type of node in XSL

Comment: Currently, it is impossible to diagnose your problem. Please edit your question and show your XSLT stylesheet, together with the XML input you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can count all preceding sibling nodes e.g. `count(preceding-sibling::node()) + 1` gives you the position based on all kind of nodes (element nodes, text nodes, comment nodes, processing instruction nodes). Or `count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1` gives you the position based on all kind of element nodes.